# Highlight field using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

For example I have this table

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>456</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this list

```
<ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>456</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to add  `style="background: yellow"` to the `<td>` element having the same value as the `<li>` element using jQuery. It should be an onclick or onhover event.

Comment: On what event or interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following;

```
$("td").on("mouseover", function () {
    var tdVal = $(this);
    $("li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == tdVal.text()) {
            tdVal.css("background", "yellow");    
        }
    });   
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "white");    
});
```

Here is a working demo: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/V9mxu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: find all values from `li` on page load

```
  var values;
  $("li").each(function(){
     values.push($(this).text());
  });
```

Step 2: Check if `td` contains that values on any desired event

```
  $(".table tr").each(function(){
      var val = $(this).text();
      if($.inArray(val,values)){
         // apply style
         $(this).css("background","yellow")
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('.table tr td').css('background','none');
    var val = $.trim($(this).text());
    $('.table tr td').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == val    
    }).css('background','yellow');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XK7qx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$elements = $('td, li');
$elements.on('click, mouseover', function () {
    var elem = this;
    $elements.each(function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = (this !== elem && this.innerHTML === elem.innerHTML && this.tagName !== elem.tagName) ? "green" : "";
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a92jV/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please check this demo and I believe that you are expecting this

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
> $( "#ulList li" ).mouseover(function() {
>     var selectedText = $( this ).text();
>     $('#tableList tr td').each(function(i, val) {
>        if(selectedText == $(val).text()){
>           $( val ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
>        }
>     });    });
>     $( "#ulList li" ).mouseout(function() {
>     $('#tableList tr td').each(function(i, val) {
>        $( val ).css( "background-color", "white" );
>
>     });    });
>  });
> ```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uHN4R/2/)